# Using python to plot histogram by category

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a table with 2 columns(say)

```
column A = {0,0,1,1,0,2,0,2,2,1,2,1}
column B = {0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.2,0.3,0.5,0.75,0.8,0.9,1.3,0.2}
```

I would like to plot a histogram of values in column B for a particular value in column A. For example: plot a single histogram only when A=0.

I tried where I can use group by to plot multiple histograms.

```
x=test['<column header a>']
y=test['<column header b>']
df['N'].hist(by=df['column header'])
```

I would like to limit to just one histogram though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filter the A first ,and then call `hist()`

```
 import pandas as pd
 df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [0,0,1,1,0,2,0,2,2,1,2,1], 'B': [0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.2,0.3,0.5,0.75,0.8,0.9,1.3,0.2]})

df[df['A']==0].hist('B')
```

[image]